# Как в параметре src="переменная", вместо слова "переменная". вставить переменную, которая будет равняться ссылке

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

```
window.myVar = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/zmlO7y2BsnI";
document.write('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + window.myVar + 'title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>"');
```

Comment: `...src="' + window.myVar + 'title...` у src двойные кавычки открыты, а где закрывающие?.. `...src="' + window.myVar + '" title...`

Answer (score 1):

```
window.myVar = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/zmlO7y2BsnI";
document.write(`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="${window.myVar}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`);
```